# how to make devise admin see everything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I normally have everything scoped with current_user

eg:

```
@integrations = current_user.integrations.all
```

For trouble shooting, I want the admin to see everything for all users. I currently have a boolean on the user model that is `admin: true`

To get around the admin seeing everything, I keep doing this:

```
def index

    if current_user.admin?
        @integrations = Integration.all.includes(:user)
        @reports = Report.all
    else
        @integrations = current_user.integrations 
        @reports = current_user.reports
    end
end
```

I feel like there is an easier way... suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe abstract the admin check to a protected/private method in your User controller:

```
def is_admin
  current_user.admin?
end
```

And then at the top of the controller, place a before action to catch whatever methods you want:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :is_admin, only: [:index, :show]
  # rest of your code
end
```

OR

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :is_admin, except: [:destroy]
  # rest of your code
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a protected method in the application_controller.rb file. As stated above it will check to see if the current_user is and admin. Then you can use conditional statements to set privileges.

assuming that admin is a boolean value

```
def is_admin?
   current_user.admin == true
end
```

In a view you can then say

```
if current_user.is_admin?
   ........ 
end
```